# Hazelcast - how to 'force' replication of Key->Values from one node to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hazelcast

I have 2 Hazelcast nodes in AWS.
One in East region and one in West.

They are connected to each other and I save key-values in that '2-node-cluster'.

Now I kill one of the nodes and still can get key-values.
Then I start again the same node and try to get key-values from it but it says that it does not have it. 2-3min later - it has all of them.

How to 'force' to do this operation faster (right away after second node joins the cluster)?

Thanks.

Comment: Data recovery should *start* as soon as the second-node joins. How long it takes depends on data volumes and network speeds. Any chance of some logs showing what you see ?

Comment: Firstly keep in mind that recommended setup is having a cluster only in the same region due to the aws network latency. Besides that, if you want to make repartitioning faster, please tell us the total data size you have on the cluster, in addition to what Neil asked. Also see: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-aws/blob/master/README.md#dealing-with-network-latency